# about right-shift operator >> in C++

Tags: c++

Here is a C++ program I see today:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LEVELS; ++i)
{
    int pyr_rows = rows >> i;      // what is the usage of >> i here ? 
    int pyr_cols = cols >> i;      // why we what to use it in this way.

    depths_curr_[i].create (pyr_rows, pyr_cols);
}
```

What I am curious about is the usage of operator >> here. I tried a simple program and type the results:

```
    int rows = 5;
int cols = 3;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    int pyr_rows = rows >> i;
    std::cout << "current i is:" << i << std::endl;     
    std::cout << "pyr_rows is: " << pyr_rows << std::endl << std::endl;

    int pyr_cols = cols >> i;
    std::cout << "current i is:" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pyr_cols is: " << pyr_cols << std::endl << std::endl;

}
```

And the result is like this:

```
current i is:0
pyr_rows is: 5

current i is:0
pyr_cols is: 3

current i is:1
pyr_rows is: 2          // from now on 
                        // the outputs of pyr_rows and pyr_cols are weird to me
current i is:1
pyr_cols is: 1           

current i is:2
pyr_rows is: 1          

current i is:2
pyr_cols is: 0

current i is:3
pyr_rows is: 0

current i is:3
pyr_cols is: 0

current i is:4
pyr_rows is: 0

current i is:4
pyr_cols is: 0
```

Why the output is like this? Can anyone explain it? And why we want to use this in this way? Any situation we prefer to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the "extraction operator", it's the right-shift operator, which is what `>>` meant before C++ started inventing crazy ways to overload it. I'm guessing from the `pyr` that this is pyramidal image processing? The idea is that every time `i` increases by one, the number of rows and columns in the pyramid are halved. That's because a right shift by i is basically a division (rounding down) by 2^i.

Comment: Funny, we start with almost the exact same wods... ;)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed the title. It's a 3D image processing program. Now it makes more clear to me now.

Answer (score 3):

In the case you've outlined, `>>` stands for the `right shift operator`. If you consider an integer written in binary form:

`01101` = 13

The `>> i` operator will make the bits above be shifted towards the right `i` times. So when `i = 2`, the above would result in:

`00011` = 3

This is useful to efficiently divide integers by powers of 2. The result ends up rounded **down**, so `3 >> 1` equals 1,  but `-3 >> 1` equals -2.

This is the `arithmetic shift`, which means the leading bit gets padded, so that negative numbers can remain negative after the shift (leading bit 1). Some languages also have the `>>>` operator for the `logical shift`, which always pads the leading bits with zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an "extraction operator", it is the original bitwise shift (right) operator, that was in C before anyone had even considered making a C++ language. It is now being used as an operator for files to input and output.

```
 int x = 4;
 int y = 1;

 cout << (x >> y) << endl;
```

will produce 4 shifted right 1 bit, which should show the value 2.